# fix position in RN StyleSheet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am rendering an item in a list like this:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.nameAddressContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.customisedName}>{place.customisedName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.address}>{place.placeName}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.deleteButtonContainer}>
        <Button
          rounded
          style={styles.deleteButton}
          onPress={() => onDeletePlace(place.id)}>
          <Icon name="trash-o" size={moderateScale(15)} color="black" />
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#d7fce4',
    borderRadius: moderateScale(20),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(8),
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    height: moderateScale(60),
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  customisedName: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(10),
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: moderateScale(35),
    height: moderateScale(35),
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  deleteButtonContainer: {
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingRight: 7,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  nameAddressContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(10),
  },
  address: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(9),
  },
});
```

When the **placeName** text is too long, it pushes the button towards the right. The button moves out of the main green view. How can I stop this from happening? Is it possible to fix the button's position while the placeName text hides or moves to the next line?

`position: fix` is invalid for React Native stylesheets. I have also tried using **zIndex** but that didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: might have to calculate the width of the container, and the size of the button and set a max width on the textbox

Comment: You could position the delete button absolute so that it will remain in the same position for all list items. However, this does not solve your problem with the long text, which I imagine, still can overflow from the green container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CSS for nameAddressContainer as

> `style = {{ flex : 1}}`

Answer (score 0):

Put your "deleteButtonContainer" style in "absolute" and add marginRight to your placeName equal to or slightly larger than the width of your DeleteButton.

Something like that:

```js
...,
deleteButtonContainer: {
    right: 8,
    top: 8,
    position: 'absolute',
},
...,
address: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(9),
    marginRight: moderateScale(38)
},
```